# 405 Method Not Allowed in Jersey is returning Tomcat's 405 page

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey, http-status-code-405

Previously, when I used Jersey on Grizzly, if I called an HTTP method that was not defined in Jersey annotations, it would return a 405 Method Not Allowed response and this was fine.

Now that I am running Jersey on Tomcat, the server returns Tomcat's specific 405 html page. How can I revert to simply sending the response with an empty body?

Answer (score 1):

As taken from this thread: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/how-to-catch-405-errors-td4937392.html

Create an exception mapper class like so:

```
@Provider
public class MyMapper implements  
ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> {
   public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException e) {
     Response r = e.getResponse();
     if (r.getStatus() == 405) {
       return Response.fromResponse(r).entity(...).build();
     }
     return r;
   }
}
```

This allowed me to capture a 405 request and return a more helpful error resource that can be parsed by applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a custom page in your webapp's web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/empty.txt</location>
</error-page>
```

Location can refer to an empty text file or JSP/Servlet/whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

My custom exception I was returning an Error object (POJO) in the Response...and my servlet server didn't know how to convert Error to JSON.

**I solved the problem by adding the following maven dependency**:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
 </dependency>
```

And my response like this:

```
@Override
public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException e) {
    Response r = e.getResponse();
    if (r.getStatus() == 405) {
        Error error = new Error(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.toString(), e.getMessage());
        return Response.fromResponse(r).status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .entity(error)
                .build();
    }
    return r;
}}
```

Actually the part which did the trick was:

```
header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```